# Why Need to declare twice in Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have just started learning TypeScript, and have been working on a small web app.

Due to state management, I have created a file called `CountdownContext.tsx`

```js
import { useState, createContext, useContext, SetStateAction } from "react";
import { CountdownContextType } from "./types";

const CountdownContext = createContext({});

export const useCountdownContext = () => {
  return useContext(CountdownContext) as CountdownContextType;
};

// React.useContext(TodoContext) as TodoContextType;

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const CountdownContextProvider: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  const [eventDate, setEventDate] = useState<Date>(new Date());

  function handleEventDate(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    setEventDate(new Date(e.target.value));
  }

  return (
    <CountdownContext.Provider value={{ eventDate, handleEventDate }}>
      {children}
    </CountdownContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And I imported eventDate and handleEventDate in the file below.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useCountdownContext } from "../../contexts/CountdownContext";
type Props = {
  activeEdit: boolean;
};

const EventDate: React.FC<Props> = ({ activeEdit }) => {
  const { eventDate, handleEventDate } = useCountdownContext();
  
  return (
    <div>
      {activeEdit ? (
        <input type="date" onChange={(e) => handleEventDate(e.target.value, typeof new Date(e.target.value))} />
      ) : (
        <div>{eventDate}</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default EventDate;
```

However, I got an error when importing. After searching about the problem happened,
I figured out that I needed to declare types.

Then I created a file below

```
export type CountdownContextType = {
  eventDate: Date;
  handleEventDate: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
};
```

However, one concern is that I thought I already provided and declared types for eventDate and handleEventDate in the context file.

Thus, I thought to question why I gotta do this twice??

Please give me a clarification about this problem. Thanks so much for your kindness and help.

Answer (score 0):

One way to not using types is to create initial value for your context like this:

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from "react";

const initialValue = {
  eventDate: new Date(),
  handleEventDate: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {},
};

const CountdownContext = createContext(initialValue);

const useCountDownState = () => {
  const [eventDate, setEventDate] = useState<Date>(new Date());

  function handleEventDate(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    console.log("setting date");
    setEventDate(new Date(e.target.value));
  }
  return { eventDate, handleEventDate };
};

const CountdownContextProvider = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) => {
  return (
    <CountdownContext.Provider value={useCountDownState()}>
      {children}
    </CountdownContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useCountdownContext = () => useContext(CountdownContext);

const EventDate = ({ activeEdit }: { activeEdit: boolean }) => {
  const { eventDate, handleEventDate } = useCountdownContext();

  return (
    <div>
      {activeEdit ? (
        <input type="date" onChange={handleEventDate} />
      ) : (
        <div>{eventDate.toDateString()}</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <CountdownContextProvider>
      <EventDate activeEdit />
    </CountdownContextProvider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

The code is heavily inspired by:
https://youtu.be/P95DuIBwnqw?t=822

And here is the source code from the link:
https://github.com/jherr/which-react-state-manager/blob/main/examples/hooks-context/src/store.tsx